# How to insert specific datetime into dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to add a new dataset into an existing table. My SQL statement is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Application ( App, Load_Date, Source)
VALUES ('unknown App', '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000','SYSTEM');
```

I get this Errormessage: `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

I tried converting with `CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000', 120)` but it didn't work.
The statement works if I use `getdate()` oder `sysdatetime()` though...

What am I missing?

Comment: As @roryap mentioned below, if you just need a placeholder for the datetime column, you may use NULL (if column nullable) or '1900-01-01'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the specific data type of your date/time column?  If it's `datetime`, for example, then `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000` is out of range, specifically 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31.

You could use a `datetime2` data type instead because that supports a range of dates between `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000` and `9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999`.  See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Well the problem is that I do'nt know if I am allowed to change the datatype (it is datetime btw).

I tried your suggestion on a test table and it works fine, but how do I crop the milli second part then?
00:00:00.000 is sufficent

Comment: It's not just about that, it's about the actual date part, too.  January 1st of the year 0001 is too early to be represented by the `datetime` data type.

Comment: Why are you trying to store such an early date anyway?  Are you trying to represent "no date"?  Does the column allow nulls?

Comment: Yes I try to refer to an 'impossible' date for the 'unknown Apps'. No nulls are allowed.
Thank you very much for the quick reply! I will go along with datetime2 then